# How to fix: "pygame.error: Couldn't open image"

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to use the **"pygame"** module to make a simple game where a character jumps across the screen. I'm currently using **python 3.7**
I watched Tech with Tim's tutorial about pygame (here the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdsNBIzsmlI)

I've already searched on Stack Overflow a solution, but not found what I was searching for. I had a similar problem when trying to open image files using the "tkinter" module.
I tried to use absolute paths and relative paths, but none of them worked.

**here are the lines that throw an error when ran**

```
win_background = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Nicholas Obert/Downloads/New/flowers 500x500px.jpg') # this is line 12

c_sprite = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Nicholas Obert/Downloads/New/frise 46x70px.png')
```

**and here's the error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nicholas Obert/PycharmProjects/Projects/pygame/test.py", line 12, in <module>
win_background = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Nicholas Obert/Downloads/New/flowers 500x500px.jpg')
pygame.error: Couldn't open C:/Users/Nicholas Obert/Downloads/New/flowers 500x500px.jpg
```

Comment: since the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) states that you should use `os.path.join()` for the filename parameter, did you try that? That's sometimes an issue on Windows since backslashes are used as path separator. Alternatively you could try r'path to image' (raw string).

Comment: @MrFuppes: forward slashes have been supported on windows for a very long time.

Comment: Pretty much without exception, if python or a python module says it can't open a file, that means that either a) you don't have permission to read the file, or b) the file literally doesn't exist. Are you 100% certain that exact path exists? What if you copy and paste that filename to a command prompt and run the `dir` command on it?

Comment: @BryanOakley, you are absolutely right. I believe I mistakenly saw backward slashes in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try :

```
win_background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Nicholas Obert\Downloads\New\flowers 500x500px.jpg') # this is line 12

c_sprite = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Nicholas Obert\Downloads\New\frise 46x70px.png')
```

also, you can do a little bit of debugging, first you should check if the file exists:

```
import os

os.path.isfile(<your_path>)
```